# module_function for Ruby Class

Tags: ruby

As I understand ruby classes, they are almost the same as modules except with an added functionality of being able to instantiate it. As `Class` inherits from `Module`, I assumed that then every class (objects of class `Class`) would have access to `module_function`, but it does not seem to be the case. When I did a difference of Module and Class' private_instance_methods, I found that `Module` has 3 methods more than `Class` - `[:append_features, :extend_object, :module_function]`

How were these functions removed from the call chain for Class objects and more importantly why?

Comment: In Ruby 2.0+ there are two more: [:prepend_features](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features) and [:refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-refine).

Answer (score 3):

Those core features are implemented in C, so discussing about that does not have generality, and is not useful. Within Ruby, you can undefine an inherited method without undefining the method in the superclass by using `undef`.

```
class Foo
  def foo; end
end
class Bar < Foo
  undef :foo
end
Foo.new.foo
# => nil
Bar.new.foo
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<Bar:0x007f85c3ce3330>
```

- `append_features` is a hook to be called right before a module is `include`-d, which a module can be, but not a class.
- `extend_object` is a hook to be called right before a module is `extend`-ed, which a module can be, but not a class.
- The purpose of `module_function` is to double the method as a class method and a private instance method, latter of which is useful when you include that module, which can be done with a module but not with a class.

Comment: but I still see "included" method in both class and modules. how can that be useful for a class? I still don't understand the need to remove "module_function". Had it been there, we can use it to write some generic methods that are supposed to be at both class and instance level!! may be it was a design decision ?!!

Comment: I don't see why module_function wouldn't be useful in a class.  Classes, too, can have both instance and class methods.  Or if not module_function, than an alternative for classes called class_function...